# Python Error "[errno 2] system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python-2.7

[image: This is the error screenshot]I am trying to code in python to download few data , the code is working for one structure but not for other, its giving me this error which i don't understand. I have written code on sublime text 3 and running it on DOS. Python version using is 2.7.11.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

url= raw_input("http://physics.iitd.ac.in/content/list-faculty-members")

html=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"border":"0","width":"100%","cellpadding":"10"})
head=soup.find("h2",attrs={"class":"title  style3"})
ready= table.find_all("tr")
header=head.find("big").find("strong")
datasets=[]
quest=[]
s=[]
test=header.get_text() 
quest.append(test)
for b in ready:

    x=[td.get_text() for td in b.find_all("td")]
    dataset =[strong.get_text() for strong in b.find("td").find("a").find_all("strong")]
    datasets.append(dataset)
    quest.append(x) 
print quest
```

Comment: Check your environment variables. Or Try to run it in Python IDLE/ Python Console. Can edit the question and paste  the code ?

Comment: Downvote: no code, and only a screen shot of the error. Don't post screen shots, copy/paste the text so we can select it, copy it, try it, google it, index it, etc.

Comment: yeah.. i can paste the code that is not the problem. @SpunkyLive

Comment: That code is *not* generating that screenshot. That code will prompt with the URL argument in `raw_input()`, something we're not seeing. Please post the real code.

Comment: Sorry but this is the exact code i have been trying to run, though on removing 'raw_input()'  and going only for the  'http' url that particular issue is resolved but i got stuck on another error. @paxdiablo

Comment: It may well be the code you were trying to run, it just happens that it cannot be the code generating that screen shot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it states `cannot find the file specified: ''` means that you're trying to open a file specified by *an empty string!*

It's a little hard to help much further since we don't have the code. The code you *have* included cannot be the code that generated that screenshot since the screenshot would have included a prompt as shown (the argument to the `raw_input()` call).

---

Clarifying that point, if that string you appear to have entered was *actually* entered, there would be no problem.

Calling `urlopen()` will in turn call `FancyUrlOpener.open()` and, being a descendant of `UrlOpener`, that's the function that receives control.

That function will intelligently select the function to use based on the scheme given.

The fact that it's choosing the file scheme rather than the HTTP one, and the fact that the exception complains about the file being an empty string, means that you are *not* passing in what you think you are.

The error message you're seeing, and the stack trace, can only occur if the following line fails (see `open_local_file()` [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/urllib.py)):

```
stats = os.stat(localname)
```

The `stat` call is only for local files, not URLs.

---

So you should be concentrating your effort: why is the string empty?

---

The most likely theory is that the code you've given the screenshot for had a *different* URL in the `raw_input` prompt and so thats what we're seeing as the prompt in the screenshot.

That would mean you simply pressed ENTER, perhaps thinking it had helpfully provided that URL as a default. That ENTER would then be taken as an emty string which would explain both the scheme selection and the empty string being used as a file name.

Comment: I am adding the code. Though thank you so much for helping out. :)

Comment: Yes i pressed enter thinking i had passed url and waited for few minutes for the result but nothing cane so i pressed enter. @paxdiablo though after removing the raw input and changing "find_all" syntax i got my answer. This code works for specific url , not for every url. So that was the main problem when i am using different url

Answer (score 0):

I have copy the url to test:

```
url = "http://www.che.iitb.ac.in/online/people/viewstudents?filter0=**ALL**&op1=&filter1=2010"
urllib.urlopen(url)
```

In fact, the url can be correctly parsed as "http", but your error msg tells us that your url are parsed as "file", so it is necessary for you to show us your really url or code.

My python version is 2.7.5.

Comment: We still don't know what your url is.Maybe you can paste your url in your code instead of "raw_input", and try it, if there is error msg,then edit your question.

Comment: Thanks i deleted the 'raw_input' and pass the url as it is , now it is working. :) @jia hilegass